# Cannot do a For Loop for cleaning multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to do a for loop for cleaning some consecutive variables but I cannot make it work

This is the repetitive code I want to avoid:

```
BD_INA$b16a1[BD_INA$b16a1=="NA"]<-"0"
BD_INA$b16a2[BD_INA$b16a2=="NA"]<-"0"
```

etc. It's from the columns 37 to 76 of a dataframe called BD_INA

And this is the loop i'm trying to make. The dataframe is called BD_INA, I'm just trying to substitute the "NA" (in text format) for "0"'s

```
bucle2 <- BD_INA %>%  for (i in 37:76(BD_INA)) {
  
  BD_INA["NA"] <- "0" 
  
}
```

I get this result: "Error in for (. in i) cols(37:76(BD_INA)) :
4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3"

Answer (score 0):

First, let's create some fake data.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~item, ~quantity,
  "saw",        2L,
  "saw",        4L,
  "saw",        6L,
  "hammer",        1L,
  "hammer",        NA,
  "hammer",        3L
)
```

Now, let's `mutate` `across` several columns. Replace with `37:76` in your case.

```
df %>% mutate(across(1:2, ~ifelse(is.na(.x),0,.x)))

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  item   quantity
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 saw           2
2 saw           4
3 saw           6
4 hammer        1
5 hammer        0
6 hammer        3
```

---

**EDIT** If NAs are character (`"NA"`) just replace `is.na(.x)` by `.x %in% "NA"`. This is better than `x=="NA"` because it returns `FALSE` if x is (really) `NA`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, Gaut. Unfortunately it doesn't work 

BD_INA %>% mutate(across(37:76, ~ifelse("NA"(.x),0,.x)))
view(BD_INA)

I think it is because "NA" is at the moment a character variable.

 Is there a way to make it via a Loop?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I edited my answer to take `"NA"`s into account.